# Controlling graph sizes when using combining graphs

Tags: graphics, stata

I am trying to combine four graphs in Stata using `graph combine`.

The result is shown in the following figure:

[image: figure]

All four figures should be of equal size but because of the horizontal `ytitle`, the first two are compressed. Is there a way to control how `graph combine` re-sizes the figures?

I have tried `ysize` and `xsize` but this seems to be overwritten by `graph combine`.

Below you can find the code that generates the figure:

```
sysuse auto, clear
graph drop _all
# delimit ;

* First 2 figures; 
twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 1, 
        sort ytitle("Some longer ytitle",  orientation(horizontal)) 
        title("Foreign", box bexpand) yla(, ang(h))  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(A1, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)));
twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 1, sort 
        ytitle("short", orientation(horizontal)) yla(, ang(h))  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(A2, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)));
graph combine A1 A2, cols(1) name(A, replace)   imargin(b=0 t=0); 

* Second 2 figures; 
twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 0, sort ytitle("") 
        title("Domestic", box bexpand)  xtitle("") xlabel(,noticks) 
        name(B1, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)) );
twoway  (line  weight mpg if foreign == 0, sort ytitle("")  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(B2, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)));
graph combine B1 B2, cols(1) name(B, replace)   imargin(b=0 t=0); 

* Combining the two
graph combine A B ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the orientation for each `ytitle` to vertical and combine the graphs only once in the desired order.

The following will give you figures of equal size as per your request:

```
sysuse auto, clear
graph drop _all
# delimit ;

* First 2 figures;

twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 1, 
        sort ytitle("Some longer ytitle",  orientation(vertical)) 
        title("Foreign", box bexpand) yla(, ang(h))  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(A1, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)));

twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 1, sort 
        ytitle("short", orientation(vertical)) yla(, ang(h))  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(A2, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)));

* Second 2 figures;

twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 0, sort ytitle("") 
        title("Domestic", box bexpand)  xtitle("") xlabel(,noticks) 
        name(B1, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)) );

twoway (line  weight mpg if foreign == 0, sort ytitle("")  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(B2, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)));

* Combining the 4 graphs;

graph combine A1 B1 A2 B2;
```

[image]

I would also recommend for the graphs in the first column to rotate their `yaxis` tick labels in a vertical angle so they match those in the graphs in the second column:

[image]

Notice that by decreasing the size of the tick value labels for both axes, you can give more prominence to the `ytitle`. You may need to adjust the spacing between the `ytitle` and the `yaxis` tick labels though.

---

**EDIT:**

You can "brute force" Stata to do what you like but you will never get exactly what you want. This is because of the variable `ytitle` length, which affects the entire graph area.

A quick solution is the following:

```
sysuse auto, clear
graph drop _all
# delimit ;

* First 2 figures;

twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 1, 
        sort ytitle("Some longer ytitle",  orientation(h)) 
        title("Foreign", box bexpand) yla(, ang(h))  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(A1, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)));

twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 1, sort 
        ytitle("                     short", orientation(h)) yla(, ang(h))  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(A2, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)));

* Second 2 figures;

twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 0, sort ytitle("") 
        title("Domestic", box bexpand)  xtitle("") xlabel(,noticks) 
        name(B1, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)) );

twoway (line  weight mpg if foreign == 0, sort ytitle("")  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(B2, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16)));

* Combining the 4 graphs;

graph combine A1 B1 A2 B2, xsize(7);
```

Notice the changes in the code, which are indicated in **bold**.

[image]

You can also play around with the values and see if you can improve things a bit:

[image]

Specifying a right margin in the `graphregion` option of the second 2 figures also improves things:

```
twoway (line weight mpg if foreign == 0, sort ytitle("") 
        title("Domestic", box bexpand)  xtitle("") xlabel(,noticks) 
        name(B1, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16) margin(r=22)));

twoway (line  weight mpg if foreign == 0, sort ytitle("")  xtitle("")
        xlabel(,noticks) name(B2, replace ) graphregion(color(gs16) margin(r=22)));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was how I started. I was asked, however, to provide horizontal ytitles. Do you think there is a possbility?

Comment: Just edited my post. If you found the answer helpful please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Comment: Good idea with the right margin in the `graphregion` option but still the asymmetry is not very satisfactory. There is also the option `fxsize` that forces Stata to overwrite the default length of the x-axis. Playing around with the numbers one may get a more symmetric figure.

Comment: What i said in my post is that you need to play around with the various options to get something close. But even with `fxsize` it is unlikely you will get exactly the result you desire.